# JS / jQuery - Filtering divs with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, filtering

I'm trying to filter some divs with checkboxes using the following code:

```
$("#filterControls :checkbox").click(function() {
  $(".sectionContent").hide();
  $("#filterControls :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    $("." + $(this).val()).show();
  });
  if($("#filterControls :checkbox").prop('checked') == false){
    $(".sectionContent").show();
  }
});
```

This works fine when you check the first checkbox, but it only filters with the others when you also have the first checkbox selected. It's hard to explain but try the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BY9JL/

I don't want it to rely on having the first checkbox checked, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var sections = $('.sectionContent');
function updateContentVisibility(){
    var checked = $("#filterControls :checkbox:checked");
    if(checked.length){
        sections.hide();
        checked.each(function(){
            $("." + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    } else {
        sections.show();
    }
}

$("#filterControls :checkbox").click(updateContentVisibility);
updateContentVisibility();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r7WS6/2/)

Comment: @Godge check the attached demo

Comment: Thanks, I still want it to show all the divs if no checkboxes are checked though.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your last if check, it will only check the first checkbox if it is checked or not.

You could change your last if block to see if there are any checked at all:

```
if($("#filterControls :checkbox:checked").length == 0){
    $(".sectionContent").show();
}
```

Comment: Ahh.. beat me to it, +1 :)

Comment: I should've explained this a bit better: if none of the checkboxes are checked, I want all the divs to reappear. Your code fixed my initial problem but stopped them all from reappearing if the checkboxes are unchecked again. Any ideas?